# How do I create a .env file in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I'm quite new to Docker and .Net Core (been using .Net Framework for ages).

I've created a new .Net Core 3 app and set it to use Docker and the app builds and runs. So far so good.
This app needs to connect to GoogleBigQuery and, as such, needs the Google Cloud credentials to be stored in an environment variable (took a frustrating hour to realise that Docker doesn't use the Windows environment variables).

From what [I've](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) [been](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) [reading](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-docker-env-file/), I would just add them to the .env file, but I don't have one in my project directory.

I've tried using the command line to set them like this `docker run containername:dev --env VAR1=value1` but I get the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "-e":
> executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I've also seen references to the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I've tried creating the .env file and tried (unsuccessfully) using the CLI to associate it with the container as follows:

```
docker run -i containername:dev --env-file .env
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "--env-file": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here. Everything I've read seems to assume that you already have a .env and I can't find anything around creating a .env manually. I did create a docker-compose.yml file which I was hoping Docker would recognise and subsequently find the .env:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  fms-techmobile-utilities:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Local.Dockerfile
    image: foo
    container_name: foo
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
```

The above didn't work, so I really don't know what else to try. I did try stopping and restarting the Docker container in the hopes that it would find the yml and env files, but nope

Answer (score 8):

`docker run containername:dev --env VAR1=value1`
is passing the command into containername:dev and asking it to run it.

Changing the order of the command to:
`docker run -e VAR1-value1 containername:dev`
will ask Docker to run the command and pass the value into the container.

To use an environment file replace the `-e` with `--env-file ./filename`. For example:
`docker run --env-file ./my_env containername:dev`

This assumes the file `my_env` is in the directory you are running the command from.

Comment: This is a great answer - thank you. I'd like to add that I think this is a ridiculous behavior of the docker CLI. If the CLI is going to ignore anything after the image name, then it should instead error if something is provided after the image name so as to not mystify developers.

Comment: @PaulG: docker does NOT ignore arguments after the imagename; it passes them to the entrypoint in the newly-created container. That entrypoint chooses what to do with them and _some_ entrypoints may ignore them, but there are plenty of images where the ability to receive such startup arguments is extremely useful and removing this functionality would be disastrous.

Answer (score 7):

## W/o Docker Compose

Docker containers do not know about environment variables on the host system. To set an environment variable in a container, you have to specify it:

```
docker run -e VARNAMEINCONTAINER='value' -i containername:dev
```

To simplify this, you can create an "env file", which is a simple text file that looks like this

```
myenvfile

VARNAME=value
FOO=bar
```

And tell docker to use it

```
docker run --env-file=myenvfile -i containername:dev
```

This will set `VARNAME` and `FOO` in your container.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

## Docker Compose

Imagine you need to start multiple containers. This would be a pain if we had to manually call `docker run...` for each container with all parameters. That's why we can use docker compose.

Docker compose has the `docker-compose.yml` file that describes what to start and replaces the docker run commands. Again, we have to provide the environment variables:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  fms-techmobile-utilities:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Local.Dockerfile
    container_name: foo
    environment:
      - FOO=bar
```

Again, we often need environment variables multiple times in a docker-compose.yml file, so we can use a text file called .env to store them:

```
.env

FOO=bar
```

and use them in docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  environment:
    -FOO
```

`.env` is the standard name for this file and docker compose will automatically look for this file. Note, that you still have to list the variable names for each service. (= variable name + value in .env and variable name only in docker-compose.yml)

Or you apply all variables from such a text file like so:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

(= make all variables from file "web-variables.env" available in this container)

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks Cristoph. I had already tried your w/o Docker suggestion to no avail. I ran the Compose installer and a console window appeared for a second and nothing else happened. I had already manually added the .env and yml files and the ENV VAR is still null at runtime. To confirm - the .env and yml files should be in web app's project directory, not in a docker/compose installation directory?

Comment: It's hard to understand how your setup looks in detail. So just some notes: If you install docker desktop, docker compose is already installed and there's no need for an additional installer. I guess, compose is not what you're looking for (for now).

Comment: (@AdamHey) The non-compose examples are wrong; `--env/-e name=val` or `--env-file file` must be _before_ (to the left of) the imagename -- note the referenced doc page shows OPTIONS to the left but only COMMAND ARGs, not anything else, to the right. Also see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538772/2868801)

Answer (score 4):

`.env` files are for docker-compose. You need to use the `docker-compose` cli instead of just `docker`.

Then you just need to do this:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and everything should work

Comment: Thanks Justin, I tried that. I'm still getting the same issue though. I have the .env and docker-compose.yml files in the project directory and my environment variable is in the .env file.
At tun time it's still null though:
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
null'

Comment: @AdamHey Read [the doc on how to set a environment variable in a container](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers). Variables defined in your `.env` files are not automatically set inside your containers.

Comment: `--env-file` is now a valid Docker option.

Answer (score 1):

you literally create a file called .env in the same location as your compose file.

you can then add env variables to the .env file such as `IMAGE=foo` then in the compose file use the line `image: ${foo}`

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the Compose installer and ran it. A console window appeared for a second and nothing else happened. In a console window in my project's directory, I ran "docker compose up" and got the following:
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)
 => [internal] load build definition from Local.Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B
I restarted the container and VS and the env var is still null at runtime

Comment: I think you might be confusing env vars and args

Comment: Not sure what you mean regarding args. I definitely need an environment variable because the Google BigQuery SDK needs the credentials to be stored as one. I have that in a .env file, but it seems docker is not seeing that file. I also created the yml file which references the env file. I tried using the console to set the variable and also to set the env file, but those commands didn't work, as per my original post

Comment: The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Answer (score -1):

Well, after lots of banging my head I found the solution and it's so simple.
In the properties page of my web app, under the Debug tab there is an Environment Variables section where you can add the key/value pairs you like. done

[image]

Thank you to everyone who took the time to reply.

I'm still left with some uncertainties though:

- Why don't the .env file and .yml files appear to be used when Visual Studio builds the app?
- When I had the docker-compose.yml file configured, why does VS seem to insist on creating a NEW container with a different name to the one in the yml file? e.g. in the yml file the container name is Foo. VS created a container called Foo_1, so the env file referenced in the yml file seems to be ignored